# cakephp set field in this->data to a related field in database

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, saving-data

I am trying to upload multiple images using meioupload which works fine if I set image.1.field and then image.2.field for each field of data. Then loop through and create/save rather than saveall.

My problem comes when I have field which is used as a subfolder for the image within an images folder. 
for example I have a form

image.1.product id
image.1.artist
image.1.file to upload
image.2.product id
image.2.artist
image.1.file to upload

now when the items are saved, all data is correct including the belongsto relationship of product id, except the second image is stored in the wrong place.
The first image is stored in images / image.1.artist / file
the second image is stored in images / image.1.artist / image.2.artist / file

This is extremely annoying, and it is simply someting to do with the way the meioupload behaviour sets the subfolder to be a field from the array.

The way I have had to resort to saving the data is by looping through and creating then saving the values, which isnt a problem, but it obviously doesnt work with this method of setting a sub folder.

So a solution could possibly be to simply set the second artist field as blank and only add multiple images for the same artist..

Or to set the data field of artist to the actual field of artist in the related product the image will belong to, but I can't seem to get this to work?

So the question is how can I set the value of this field to the related products artist field that is already in the database for each seperate create/save?

ps. I am sorry if this is a bit long winded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right so the problem came because I was sending $this->data as 2 arrays. The solution was to read this->image->product->field('artist') and set it to this->data['Image'][1]['artist'].

This way it sets the field in the first array to artist, which in this particular meioupload behaviour will roll over to the second array of data and hence the image upload (which will then be suffixed with a /) This allows me to upload the images to their corresponding artist directory whilst creating 3 thumbnails and saving the relations, file info and so on.

I found that this doesn't seem to make a difference to loading the images (images work fine even though the display code effectively has two / in it, because the second image will be saved in the database as /dir/artist/ as a pose to the first one which is saved /dir/artist)

IF anyone has an ingenious way to call meioupload one at a time then this would hopefully avoid this slight issue, and then more and more images could be added into the same form..alas I am not clever enough to know how to do this yet..
Any help would be much appreciated!!!!